# JSP/HTML: Trying to pass html input to multiple objects that have the same variable name for use

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm stuck with some homework and I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for or one that will work in my case.  I'm try to make a simple math quiz that will check the answers upon clicking submit.  I started out trying to do this with jstl to loop the creation process but couldn't seem to grasp how to get it working.  My current code is a mess that I know can be done much better, but I'm trying to get a working product at this point.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Where I'm at right now I am trying to link my objects to the input box I want them to use, but because my variable names are the same all the others are being over written.  I've isolated two of the math problems while trying to get this working.  The follow code is very bad but is my current skill level with java and html.

**Java bean:**

```java
public class MathGen {

private int a;
private int b;
private int c;
private String problem;
private String check;

public MathGen (){
    //Generate random numbers a and b

    int randA = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    int randB = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*100);
    if (randA < randB){
        a = randB;
        b = randA;
    }
    else {
        a = randA;
        b = randB;
    }
    this.problem = (a + " - " + b + " = ");

}

public String getProblem () {

    return problem;
}

/**
 * @param c the c to set
 */
public void setC(int c) {
    this.c = c;
}

/**
 * @return the check
 */
public String getCheck() {
    if ((a - b) != c){
        this.check = c + " is INCORRECT";
    }
    else {
        this.check = c + " is CORRECT";
    }
    return check;
}

}
```

**JSP Page:**

```jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <form  action="answercheck.jsp" >


    <jsp:useBean id="problem" scope="session" class="MyClass" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="problem" property="problem"/>
    <input type="text" name="c[]" value="" id="problem" size="2"/><br>


    <jsp:useBean id="problem1" scope="session" class="MyClass" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="problem1" property="problem"/>
    <input type="text" name="c[]" value="" id="problem1" size="2"/><br>

    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form the parameters are used by name, so if you have two objects `problem` and `problem1` you should use the name of the object in the input name.

```jsp
<input type="text" name="problem.c" value="" id="problem" size="2"/><br>
<input type="text" name="problem1.c" value="" id="problem1" size="2"/><br>
```

In another jsp you can use `jsp:setProperty` to populate a bean from parameter.

> ## Syntax of `jsp:setProperty` action tag
>
> ```
> <jsp:setProperty name="instanceOfBean" property= "*"   |   
> property="propertyName" param="parameterName"  |   
> property="propertyName" value="{ string | <%= expression %>}"   
> />
> ```

Comment: Thank you.  I feel so dumb that I missed it and now realize how important the "param" tag is to sorting user input to objects.

Comment: I understand, in the future if you have more questions, don't forget to come back and upvote this answer.